# Are iframes still a risk if source and target sites have NOT been compromised

Tags: security, iframe

This is a web security "concept" question:

If you own 2 websites (A and B). AND you iframe in some content from B onto A. AND both websites have NOT been physically compromised (by "compromised" I mean that some hacker hasn't changed the source code on any page on the web server itself, and for the purposes of this theoretical discussion you can guarantee that). THEN, is there any (known) methods in exploiting frames in other ways?

The reason I ask this is that Youtube, Google Maps etc. are now providing iframe code as their default "embedding" method and we are internally having a debate about the wisdom of that!

If the only way that iframes can be exploited is by physically modifying the source code, we are proposing to build an system to actively monitor any changes to those few files we host that will contain an iframe tag. Do you think that is a satisfactory mitigation strategy?

Cheers, and thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure where the concern is in the theoretical scenario. If you've "guaranteed" that your source and target are not compromised then what exactly is the security concern? If the source page with the iframe is 100% guaranteed (again, in the theoretical scenario) then why worry about it? Perhaps there is an element missing from your question? You're basically saying "this safe is 100% locked. Can someone get into the safe?".

Comment: I think he's asking whether there's some way the user can exploit the fact that the embedding is done using iframes to perform something malicious to one of the sites, without having to compromise the site contents themselves. E.g. by using Developer Tools.

Comment: Yup. That's it. I know it is a *theoretical question* because no-one can  guarantee that a web server won't be compromised these days... but I am just trying to answer the fundamental question in my own mind: "iframe attacks are only possible if the web servers themselves are compromised". From what I have learnt to date, it would seem that that is the case! Thanks.